# QML DropShadow performance issue on android app

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I stumbled upon this problem some time ago and made this post: [Is my QML android application running on software and how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778773/is-my-qml-android-application-running-on-software-and-how-can-i-fix-this).

The answers suggested that the app ***is*** actually being rendered on GPU and I just need to optimize my code with a profiler but I didn't find any kind of complicated bindings or anything that could be significantly optimized. But I did notice that shadows are what causes all the lags. I decided to experiment with it and created a very simple program: two spinning rectangles with a shadow applied to both of them.

---

Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

import MyFpsText 1.0


Window {
    id: mw
    visible: true

    MyFpsText {
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top

        width: 100
        height: 100

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pixelSize: 20
            text: parent.fps
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: 200

        width: 200
        height: 50

        color: "skyblue";

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: DropShadow {
            radius: 50
            samples: 101
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: 500

        width: 200
        height: 50

        color: "skyblue";

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: DropShadow {
            radius: 50
            samples: 101
        }
    }


    RotationAnimator {
        target: rect1

        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite

        from: 0
        to: 360
        duration: 2000
    }
}
```

I also used a custom element `MyFpsText` that I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35557449/12694438).

---

Now the results. Stack Overflow doesn't allow gifs over 2 MB, so they are on imgur: https://imgur.com/a/G0LoRsy

1. First, without shadows - everything is fine, 120fps
2. Shadow parameters: `radius: 30` `samples: 61` (as suggested in the official documentation, `samples = 2 * radius + 1`). The lag is already quite visible as the fps dropped to 30
3. And the worst: `radius: 50`, fps -- 11

---

So. It's definitely not a bad code problem and the app is rendered on hardware (according to the answer to the previous post). So what is it? What can I do about this?

I'm using Qt 5.12.2

---

Also, one more question as it might be related. There's a similar problem on desktop as well. Although it's not about fps: the UI lags when I resize the window (of any qml app, this one or anything else I make). This one though is solved by setting `qputenv("QT_OPENGL", "angle");`, but someone said that it's more of a hack and that `angle` is CPU rendered (yet, it runs much better for some reason, but whatever).

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176929/qt-quick-very-slow-painting) says that it was fixed in qt 5.9.2, but I'm using qt 5.15.2 and it's not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll see better results if you turn on the `cached` property:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-dropshadow.html#cached-prop

Comment: Wow, it actually worked, I thought I've tried that before. Thanks! didn't expect it to be that simple...